# Identify the lyrics of KISS' God Of Thunder (Alive 2)

Tags: lyrics, rock, live-music

Following the drum solo of KISS' [God of Thunder from Alive II](https://youtu.be/F1X-3RQtbls?t=245) and before the "I'm the lord of the wastelands", could you identify what is being said?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Peter Criss on the drums!", and then possibly a count-in "one...two...".

You can hear the Peter Criss introduction on other recordings, like this one: https://youtu.be/rQzLnyToloE. (Edit: at 9:14-ish)